# Pegar dados do option

Tags: php

Galera me tira uma duvida. Como que obtenho 2 valores de um option em php?

exemplo :

```
<option value="pegar aqui">(Pegar aqui)</option>
```

já tentei usar foreach mas não to conseguindo só vem o value. Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Cadê o `select` no seu código?

Comment: desculpa, eu só coloquei a parte principal o código a assim. <select name="servico[]"> <option value="pegar aqui">(Pegar aqui)</option> </select>

Comment: Você quer fazer um SELECT com múltiplas opções, ou quer pegar o valor que está em `value` e entre a tag `option`? Acho que não entendi essa parte direito.

Comment: Isso, eu quero pegar os dois resultados, primeiro do value e depois o que está dentro do option

Comment: Mas você quer fazer isso pelo PHP ou pelo Javascript? E os valores são diferentes?

Comment: PHP, sim no value eu preciso colocar numeros e no option textos

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56696/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-heitor-deep).

Comment: Apenas o valor em `value` é enviado na requisição. O conteúdo dentro das tags serve apenas para melhor informar seu usuário. Se ambos os valores não representam a mesma coisa, seu sistema está inconsistente.

Comment: Já que o autor da pergunta deixou claro que o problema é outro, estou votando pra fechar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O formulário submeterá apenas os valores.

Para obter os labels dos elementos tipo "option", terá que criar alguma lógica envolvendo avaScript ou uma gambiarra no próprio atributo "value" do elemento.

Uma ideia simples:

```
<option value="valor">label</option>
```

Você quer receber "valor" e "label" então poderia fazer algo assim

```
<option value="valor:label">label</option>
```

No PHP recebe normalmente e abstrai os dados com funções de manipulação de strings

```
$str = $_POST['nome_do_select'];
$str_arr = explode(':', $str);
echo $str_arr[0]; // valor
echo $str_arr[1]; // label
```

Uma alternativa a isso é usando JavaScript, no momento que submete o formulário, antes de realmente ser enviado, o JavaScript faria leitura dos elementos e criaria campos hidden vinculados de alguma forma com aquele elemento.

Então no PHP que recebe os dados verificaria esses vínculos checando a existência desses campos ocultos. 
Acho isso mais complicado. Recomendo resolver da forma mais simples.

Se quiser ainda pode mesclar ambas as lógicas.

Usando JavaScript, concatene o label ao valor no momento que a página é carregada. Assim o valor original não precisa necessariamente já vir com o label incluso no value.